# Permission denied, while trying to launch a python script from inside a python script using OS

Tags: python, permission-denied

I'm using this python script to try to launch, another. The intention is to do this multiple times so that I can launch 4 similar scripts with just one command. 
"
    import os

```
os.system("/path/to/file/.../script.py")
```

"
However when I run the script I get : Permission denied

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing scripts and py files instead of doing an OS workaround.
You could compile your scripts as modules into scripts.py and do

```
import [something] from scripts
```

Or you could wrap it all up in a main() operation and run scripts in your current file.

Hope this helps. I'd reserve using os.system() to run exe files or things outside of Python's immediate scope.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and is more suited as a comment. You don't know if the script is in Python's immediate scope, it could very well be a completely different program.

Comment: That's fair.
I mentioned the scope and it's worth considering.
Unfortunately, I'm new to StackOverflow so my rep isn't high enough to place comments yet!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead